# Load default image if image is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net website, I am building certain pages dynamically.  There are certain images that I load from my server.  If the image is not present, then I need to load a default image instead.

Until now I've been checking to see if the url is valid, and if it is, then I know the image is present.  If the url is invalid, then I know, in my code, to supply my default image.  To that end, I've done this:

```
    //returns true if the url actually exists
    //however, this will ALWAYS throw an exception if it exists, so beware the debugger.
    public static bool IsValidUrl(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        httpReq.Method = "HEAD";
        httpReq.KeepAlive = false;
        httpReq.Timeout = 2000;
        HttpWebResponse httpRes = default(HttpWebResponse);
        bool exists = false;
        try {
            httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
            if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                exists = true;
            }
        } catch {
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

But that isn't really a good way to do things, and I don't like having to proof against the exception like that.  Also, if I add new images, the server doesn't think the new images are valid urls until a certain time has passed (or I restart the website in IIS) - this is the bugger that has led me to look for another method.

Is there a better way to supply a default image that will display in case my chosen image is not present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use a client-side solution, this might work for you:

```
<img src="fakesrc" onerror="setDefaultImage(this);" />
```

the function:

```
function setDefaultImage(img)
{
    //set default.
    img.src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
}
```

The img will try to load from its original `src` attribute, and it will trigger the `onerror` event if the image does not exist. The `setDefaultImage()` method will set the image a default one.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q64hn/

**EDIT**:

If the files are in your server, you could let the file system take care of that:

```
public static bool IsValidUrl(string url) {
    return System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(url));
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool x = IsValidUrl(ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Very nice answer.  I was actually thinking of that.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Pretty obscure. +10 if I could.

Comment: Ah, I found a good addition: as I am using the code from a dll, I don't have any `Page` reference by which to use `ResolveUrl`, so I borrowed a very nice function from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53460/ResolveUrl-in-ASP-NET-The-Perfect-Solution  and used it instead.  Now I can use *that* in my dll!

Comment: @BGM that's pretty neat. I am glad that you figured it out! :D

Comment: Ah, in fact, I went wholly with the check on the file system - since the files are all on my server, that is a much better approach, anyway.  However, I'm putting your javascript fix in my notebook.